# How to fall back an outbound call to the SIM account from a custom Android phone account?

Tags: java, android, telephony, telephonymanager

I implemented a custom `PhoneAccount` by extending `ConnectionService` and normally this account is set as default.
I search for a solution to send outgoing calls over the SIM account if inside `onCreateOutgoingConnection` the code detects the alternate service is not available or fails to start the call.

I wanted to use `ConnectionService.createRemoteOutgoingConnection()` but I didn't find a way to create a `Connection` from the returned `RemoteConnection`